# How to proceed game dialogue by pressing a button?

Tags: java, jtextarea

I am trying to make a text-based RPG and have a question about how to proceed the story dialogue (I'm still quite new to Java).

I want to change the content of text area by pressing a button so the dialog continues everytime you press the button.

For example, if there's a dialog like this,

> Hello. I have never seen your face before.
>
> You look like an adventurer.
>
> So you also came to kill that wizard?

I want to display these texts one by one, not at once.

Here's my code:

```
package test;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Dialogue extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
//Window
JFrame window;
Container con;  
//Font
Font basicfont;
Font bigfont;
Font timesnewroman; 
//Main game screen  
JPanel storyP;
JPanel inputP;
JPanel enterP;
//Main game screen Panel 3
JTextArea storyT;
//Main game screen Panel 5
JLabel inputA;
JTextField input;
JButton enterB;

            
public static void main(String[]args)
{       
    
    Dialogue game = new Dialogue();
    game.setup();
                    
}

public void setup()
{
    window = new JFrame();
    window.setBounds(0,0,1200,950);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
    window.setLayout(null); //Disabling the default layout.
    window.setVisible(true);                        
    basicfont = new Font("MS Gothic", Font.PLAIN, 24);
    bigfont = new Font("MS Gothic", Font.BOLD, 28);                                 
    con = window.getContentPane();
        
    // Panel Setup                              
    storyP = new JPanel(); //This is where story text is displayed.
    storyP.setBounds(50, 500, 800, 320);
    storyP.setBackground(Color.white);
    storyP.setLayout(new GridLayout());     
    
    inputP = new JPanel();
    inputP.setBounds(50, 830, 500, 50);
    inputP.setBackground(Color.black);
    inputP.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    //p5.setLayout(new GridLayout());
    
    enterP = new JPanel();
    enterP.setBounds(600, 830, 120, 50);
    enterP.setBackground(Color.black);                          
    
    //STORY TEXT SETUP
    storyT = new JTextArea();   
    storyT.setFont(basicfont);
    storyT.setBackground(Color.black);
    storyT.setForeground(Color.white);      
    storyT.setEditable(false);      
    
    //INPUT BOX SETUP
    inputA = new JLabel(">");
    inputA.setBackground(Color.black);
    inputA.setForeground(Color.white);
    inputA.setFont(bigfont);            
    input = new JTextField(15);
    input.setBackground(Color.black);
    input.setForeground(Color.white);
    input.setBorder(null);      
    input.setFont(bigfont);
    input.addActionListener(this);      
    
    enterB = new JButton("ENTER");
    enterB.setFont(timesnewroman);
    enterB.addActionListener(this);
    
    //ADDING
    storyP.add(storyT);
    inputP.add("West",inputA);
    inputP.add(input);
    enterP.add(enterB);

    //VISIBILITY
    con.add(storyP);
    con.add(inputP);
    con.add(enterP);
                
    
    Opening();
}


public void Opening()
{                                               
    storyT.setText("Hello. I have never seen your face before.");               
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{

    if(e.getSource()==enterB)
    {
        storyT.setText("You look like an adventurer.");
    }

        
}


}
```

I could change the text from "Hello. I have never seen your face before" to "You look like an adventurer" by pressing ENTER button that I created.

But I don't know how to go further(to display "So you also came to kill that wizard?") from this point since my ENTER button's action is assigned to display a specific text ("You look like an adventurer").
I don't even know where to write the 3rd line so it is not written in this code yet.

Comment: You could use an array of strings that contains the entire conversation. Than simply iterate through as the user presses enter. You could use a counter to switch to the next bit in the conversation or some other clever method.

Comment: Yes it seems that's one way to do it. Thanks for the info :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a counter and a loooong switch:

```
counter++;
switch(counter){
    case 0: storyT.setText("You look like an adventurer.");
    case 1: storyT.setText("So you also came to kill that wizard?");
    case 2: ....
}
```

But it will be quite bad if you will have hunderds of texts.
For this i would use array of Strings or an ArrayList. then you can use counter to get to index of text to print
It will be much better if you will have these texts in a file. Than you can read it line by line with Scanner class.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("texts.txt"));
ArrayList<String> texts = new ArrayList<String>();
while(sc.hasNextLine())
    text.add(sc.nextLine());
sc.close();
```

it throws FileNotFoundException I think
Than your linstener content could be:

```
storyT.setText(texts.get(counter++));
```

The variable texts should be declared as an instance variable, not in method body:

```
private ArrayList<String> texts;
....
....
....
texts=new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: I tried your method with counter and switch and it worked just fine! About the method with ArrayList and Scanner...it sounds very promising and actually I had a feeling that I will have to adopt that kind of method sooner or later. Considering my current Java level, scanning data in another file still sounds a bit advanced but I will try. Thank you so much for all the useful information!

Comment: I know what you mean, Scanner is something a bit advanced, anyway I'm glad it helps @Ryi

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I'd do this...

declare a Stack.

```
Stack<String> texts = new Stack<String>();
```

A stack is like a physical stack. It has two main methods. Push(String a) and pop(). Push will put a String on top of the stack and pop() will return the String that is on the bottom.

In your main method, you simply fill this stack with the texts you want.

e.g.

```
texts.push("you look like an adventurer");
texts.push("etc..");
texts.push("etc..");
```

then, in you actionlistener, you just do this instead of what you had:

```
 storyT.setText(texts.pop());
```

if you want some safety measures, you can do this:

```
if (texts.hasnext())
storyT.setText(texts.pop());
```

This checks if the stack still has texts stored up in it. If not, the stack won't be popped, in which case you'll get null, which isn't good.

Comment: Thank you! I tried your method and it seems to be working pretty good. But I have one problem. When you press the Enter button, my current code displays the 3rd line first. Then it displays 2nd line then 1st line. So the order is reversed. I can correct the order by writing the dialogue in reverse order but it makes the code confusing so hopefully I want to avoid that. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Nope, that's how a stack works. The first thing you put in with push() will be the first thing you get out with pop(). So just add the strings in the appropriate order. In your case, just reverse the order you push the strings. May I suggest a linked list instead. Read up about it!